# Find first 3 biggest numbers in multiple tables [EXCEL]

Tags: excel

I want to get the first 3 biggest numbers in multiple tables:

```
Sheet 1:
Name1   7
Name2   10
Name3   5

Sheet 2:
Name1   45
Name2   3
Name3   1

Sheet 3:
//I want to get 45, 10 and 7
```

- The function LARGE can only find what I want but for just one table.
  LARGE(B1:B3,1) LARGE(B1:B3,2) LARGE(B1:B3,3)
  Any attempt to add multiple tables on the first argument fail
  I tried then to concatenate arrays, but no luck.

Comment: Are these data tables? Are the values in the same column on each table?

Comment: yes, they are in the same column but in separate sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about: `LARGE(Sheet1:Sheet2!B:B, 1)`, `LARGE(Sheet1:Sheet2!B:B, 2)`, and `LARGE(Sheet1:Sheet2!B:B, 3)` -- assuming column B is the column of interest on each sheet/table.

Comment: Try holding `Shift` while selecting cells on adjacent sheets to get a feel for how this works. Can be *very* useful at times.